# Get the same password for the same string

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a code to generate the same password for the string presented.
Like a challenge and response.

I want to do a very simple winform based on c# in which I will enter a name and get a random string that represent the password for this name.

For example: I will enter "Bob", click on "Generate password" and get for example "hakdn11jhfh32" (something random), then for the name "David" I'll get another password, but when I'll enter "Bob" again I will get the same password for Bob before ("hakdn11jhfh32").

Is there an easy way?

I actually thought of just giving some characters for one character (like: a=8j2, 5=j1mm.....) and then just do a replace for every name given.
But I'm hoping that there is something easier and more automatic.

Comment: As @cydrickT as said, it seems you are wanting to store the hash of the username as a password. While this is very simple to do in C#, I DO NOT recommend that you do this, as it's an extreme security vulnerability.

Comment: As far as I know, storing a hashed+salted password is the best way to handle login. Is there any other way that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is hashing. Here's an official article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602%28v=cs.70%29.aspx

Also, this article provides a small piece of code:

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/c-hash-encryption-example.62293/

```
public string GeneratePasswordHash(string thisPassword)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] tmpSource;
    byte[] tmpHash

    tmpSource = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(thisPassword); // Turn password into byte array
    tmpHash = md5.ComputeHash(tmpSource);

    StringBuilder sOuput = new StringBuilder(tmpHash.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpHash.Lenth; i++)
    {
        sOutput.Append(tmpHash[i].ToString(“X2”));  // X2 formats to hexadecimal
    }
    return sOutput.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property of pseudo-random number generator that lets you seed its sequence. Make a random number generator like this:

```
String name = "Bob";
Random rnd = new Random(name.hashCode());
```

Now you can generate a string of random character codes using the `rnd.nextInt(numChars)`, where `numChars` is the number of characters that can appear in the password:

```
StringBuilder pwd = new StringBuilder();
int numCharInPassword = 8;
String legalChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*/{}[]\|";:<>()+=";
for (int i = 0 ; i != numCharInPassword ; i++) {
    pwd.append(legalChars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(legalChars.length())));
}
```

This guarantees that starting with the same name and using the same pre-set password will produce the same password. Sometimes, a different name could produce the same password, too, but that is unlikely.