# Generating the same password for any given string?

Tags: hash, password-hash, mit-scratch

Good morning/afternoon/evening guys!

So I've been assigned for a class the following task: make a Scratch (:/ not the funnest language lol) program that takes an input string, and outputs a password. However, the password should be reproduceable using the same seed. I did some searching and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536158/get-the-same-password-for-the-same-string) saying that this is called hashing. Cool, I'm pretty sure this is what I need to do.

Here's the problem: using that to generate a password. So I have code that works that generates a unique random password [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/259507602/). I should be able to adapt that easily.

My current thought process is: if I take the ASCII value of the character and multiply by a prime number and then multiply by the character index of it (something like `(64 * 239 * 1) + (85 * 239 * 2)`), I should get a unique number for most strings (right?). Then I add them up and use that number to do something and generate a 6-7 character password.

What can I do to take this basic hash and get a 6-7 character password (a-z, A-Z, !, $, and % for my charset but don't worry about that part). More-so, how might I do this in Scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: You're essentially being asked to write and implement your own hashing algorithm, and (I would assume) that the complexity of that is restricted to your own imagination. If you don't need a fixed length, don't try for that as it's very complex, and simply do an `if char = a, encode as b` approach. It would be very difficult to code a fixed-length algorithm in Scratch, but I personally think you're on the right track. If you do need a fixed length, [*this answer*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1301/52671) might be able to help you.

Comment: That's fine, I don't need a fixed length necessarily, but I don't want only numbers. In fact, I don't want numbers at all. I'd like to take that number and use it to convert to any characters a-Z, !, $, and %...Am I taking the wrong approach entirely for this output?

Comment: What is your input alphabet?

Comment: @JimMischel a-z, A-Z, !, $, and % for my charset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that I made: 
[image: This is the code I made]

What it does is iterate through the string and check it against each item in the alphabet by iterating through it and then when it finds a match it will do the math and add the value to the hash. Is this what you were looking for? I hope it helps.
ASCII list:

```
1  97
2  98
3  99
4  100
5  101
6  102
7  103
8  104
9  105
10 106
11 107
12 108
13 109
14 110
15 111
16 112
17 113
18 114
19 115
20 116
21 117
22 118
23 119
24 120
25 121
26 122
27 37
28 33
29 36
```